# "Unable to detect the URI-scheme of..."

Tags: desktop

Lately this has become a more frequent error message here. In this case, I installed the `MPLAB X IDE`, and it seems the installation does not create a `.desktop` file. So I copied one of smaller `.desktop` files and created:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Version=5.15
Name=Uninstall_MPLAB_X_IDE_v5.15
Categories=Development;
Comment=Uninstall
Icon=
Exec=/usr/local/opt/microchip/mplabx/v5.15/mplab_platform/bin/mplab_ide
Terminal=false
```

The file seems valid, as the item appears in the menu, but, on clicking the entry nothing happens. WIth `xdg-open mplab.desktop`, I get the message

```
Unable to detect the URI-scheme of mplab.ide
```

`mplab_ide` is a shell script (and has `#!/bin/sh` at the top). And it's marked executable. I tried setting `Terminal=true`, tried adding Path:...

-What causes the error message?

-Is there any documention on this? (searching brings up plenty of other victims, but not really any explanation or solution)